# I run rasa in docker containers but I can't get webchat working

Tags: docker, chatbot, rasa, web-chat

I got my 5 rasa chatbots running in different docker containers but when I try use webchat it fails. I can run rasa with webchat in normal linux server.

> I don't get error messages just no webchat chat window.

CORRECTION: This error I get
"Unable to correct
Firefox can't estabilish a connection to the server at localhost:5005"

Here is command I run

```
docker run --name=rasa1 --user 1000 -v $(pwd):/app rasa/rasa:1.10.11-full run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug
```

Here is my environment:

```
Ubuntu 18.04
Docker 19.03.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not expose any ports.

Assuming rasa is listening on port 5005 inside the container, try:

```
docker run --name=rasa1 --user 1000 -v $(pwd):/app -p "5005:5005" rasa/rasa:1.10.11-full run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug
```

Edit:

I managed to make it run by trial and error. The steps are below:

1. Init the project

   ```
       mkdir app
       docker run -it --rm --user 1000 -v $(pwd)/app:/app rasa/rasa:1.10.11-full init --no-prompt
   ```
2. Edit `$(pwd)/app/credentials.yml` and add the following lines:

   ```
       socketio:
         user_message_evt: user_uttered
         bot_message_evt: bot_uttered
         session_persistence: true
   ```
3. Start rasa:

   ```
       docker run --name=rasa1 --user 1000 -v $(pwd)/app/app:/app -p "5005:5005" rasa/rasa:1.10.11-full run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug
   ```

4.Create `$(pwd)/index.html` with the following contents:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Webchat</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="webchat"></div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.min.js"></script>
        // you can add a version tag if you need, e.g for version 0.11.5
        https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@0.11.5/lib/index.min.js
        <script>
            WebChat.default.init({
                selector: "#webchat",
                initPayload: "/get_started",
                customData: { "language": "en" }, // arbitrary custom data. Stay minimal as this will be added to the socket
                socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
                socketPath: "/socket.io/",
                embedded: true,
                title: "Welcome",
                subtitle: "to my chatbot",
                params: { "storage": "session" } // can be set to "local"  or "session". details in storage section.
            })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

5. Open `$(pwd)/index.html` in your browser.
6. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, now the rasa part is working.  Webchat doesn't still work  
First I give command you proposed  Then I double clik index.html, so this opens in browser  
>file:///home/linttu/rasaProd/rasa1/index.html  
Now I should see chatbot but I only see message this below  
"// you can add a version tag if you need, e.g for version 0.11.5 https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@0.11.5/lib/index.min.js"  
Here is link where you can see full index.html  
"https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat"  
It looks like the javascript doesn't work?

Comment: I managed to make it work. See my edit for details.

Comment: Thank you very much even I couldn't get it directly working according your instructions. When I run command 3. I get this error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: models". But I got it working by running same command in folder where rasa files are. I run this command: "docker run --name=rasa60 --user 1000 -v $(pwd):/app -p "5005:5005" rasa/rasa:1.10.11-full run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug"

Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you managed to get it to work. Please accept my answer.